# Print direct, no window prompt, number of copies, PHP Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, printing, epson

I have an intranet website system on php. When Print Tickets, I do not wish to receive the myWindow.print();  prompt window and wish to assigned it number of copies to print in php and javascripst/jquery code.

My current sample code is as such

```
function PrintTicket()
{
    myWindow=window.open('','','width=200,height=100');
    myWindow.document.write("<p>Ticket No: '12345'</p>");
    myWindow.document.close();  
    myWindow.focus();
    myWindow.print(); 
}
```

Please advise how can I do so as printer EPSON do not take number of copies as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because the only browser's JavaScript API exposed is the print one which requires user interaction.
It's also a security matter, imagine a web page that prints hundreds of pages without user approval.
Also, JavaScript can't view printers connected to computer or other devices enumeration for the same security purpouse.